# disable ReCaptcha verification during mobile number verification in my Android Studio User authentication app?

Tags: firebase, android-studio

Remove ReCaptcha verification from my app.

every time I verify my mobile number, a default browser opens for device verification

Also, enable Google Play Integrity API in the Firebase console. my google JSON file is up to date in android studio. Added SHA1 and SHA-256 in my firebase.